# Haskell - Declaring the type of multiple functions

Tags: haskell, types, declaration

I often find myself writing multiple functions with the same type. Let's call this type `FuncType`. I might write something like this:

```
funcA :: FuncType
funcB :: FuncType
funcC :: FuncType
funcD :: FuncType

-- Implementations
```

This feels like a lot of unnecessary typing (typing as in tapping on the keyboard, not declaring types of functions). Is there maybe some way to do this more concisely? What I want would look something along the lines of:

```
(funcA, funcB, funcC, funcD) :: FuncType

-- Implementations
```

I really tried to google this but I came up empty. If this isn't a feature of the language, why not? Am I missing something? Am I doing something wrong if I find myself needing this?

Comment: For short expressions you can write things like `[x, y] = [3, 4 :: Int]`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do what you tried without the parentheses.

```
funcA, funcB, funcC, funcD :: FuncType
```

---

In the [Haskell 2010 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/), you can see in [chapter 4 (Declarations and Bindings)](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-620004) that a type signature (`gendecl`) looks like this:

```
vars :: [context =>] type
```

and `vars` look like this:

```
var-1 , … , var-n
```

Which is exactly the form you're looking for.

---

Sidenote: Haddock will apply a documentation if it finds it around that type signature *to every symbol* in that (`vars`) list.

Comment: REALLY!? Can't believe I tried with parentheses but not without. Maybe this was to obvious for me to find when googling. Either way, THANK YOU!

Comment: @EFTH Hehe I feel you :P who hasn't been there. I'm going to update my answer to show it in the language spec. Best of luck!

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to MasterMastic's answer, you can also *actually* give the repeated type a name using a type declaration:

```
-- | why GoodName is a good name
type GoodName = Complicated -> Function -> Type

-- | Foo explanation.
foo :: GoodName
foo = ...

-- | Bar explanation.
bar :: GoodName
bar = ...
```

This way, you only need to repeat the name instead of the potentially much longer type. Benefits of this style over `foo, bar :: Complicated -> Function -> Type` include:

- the named type serves as documentation
- the named type can be reused elsewhere
- the function definitions and type signatures are next to each other
- you can have different haddock comments for the different functions
- your source code looks more regular
- if only one of the functions later gets refactored to take additional arguments, the change is more local.

Of course, you can also combine these approaches as `foo, bar :: GoodName`. Because of type inference, you can usually even leave out the type signature altogether and let the compiler figure out the type.

Comment: `FuncType` in the question is (or was at least in my mind when I wrote it) a longer type that has been given a more convenient name with a type declaration. I felt however that having `FuncType` appear repeatedly in the code still was too much too type. Though, I do agree that this isn't always the best way to go. I often prefer having the type signature right next to the definition, but sometimes that isn't the case.

Comment: For clarity, what I wanted in the context of the code you preseneted:`foo, bar :: GoodName`

Comment: I added the `foo, bar :: GoodName` to the question, and also mentioned type inference. I understand that you're happy with MasterMastic's answer, but I want to chart the design space for future readers.